# Access is denied on mklink

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, mklink

I am trying to get a symlink working over a network drive.

I have already tried suggestions on questions already asked, such as running as administrator and checking if the directory already exists. Unfortunately it still gives me the following error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>mklink /d \\myserver\someLink \\myserver\mydir
Access is denied.
```

Any ideas how I could get this working? The local machine is running windows 7 and the remote machine is running windows server 2008 R2 standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I jumped through all the hoops:

1. Create a non-admin account (in my case, activated the `guest` account).
2. As `Admin`, run `secpol.msc` and grant this account `Create Symbolic Link` permissions.
3. `runas /user:guest cmd` to open a command window as the guest.

   only to get caught on the simplest problem: because I was running as `guest`, I didn't have write permissions within the directory. So,
4. As admin, change permissions in the target directory (where you want to make the link) to give write access to the non-admin user.

Comment: If I can `mkdir foo`, is that indicative that I have the necessary permissions? I had already given the "Create Symlink" permissions to the whole `Users` group. This is on a mapped network drive.

Comment: Note for future visitors: If your account *has* admin permissions, and you are trying to run as that account, [you have to disable UAC](http://superuser.com/questions/124679/how-do-i-create-a-link-in-windows-7-home-premium-as-a-regular-user#comment788686_311078) (because "reasons").

Answer (score 1):

I had this while I wanted to create a hard link with  `mklink /H ...`.
By removing the `/H`, the error vanished as well.

So if a symbolic link does the trick for you as well, you should try this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little silly, but make sure you're using /D (soft) or /J (hard) for directories or you'll get access denied.